# Is "empowerment" condescending?

Tags: terminology

Many organizations claim that their mission is to empower a certain group of people. Common examples are women's empowerment, employee empowerment, healthcare patient empowerment.

I work in a collectible niche as part of a company that uses technology to improve the experience of these collectors. For example, think Kelley Blue Book for cars. We provide various tools to collectors to facilitate and improve upon the existing buying/selling process. From a marketing standpoint, we may make the claim that our mission is dedicated to "collector empowerment".

However, I'm not a huge fan of this term as I perceive it to be somewhat condescending. In my opinion, to say that your organization's mission is the empowerment of a group implies that group is for some reason incapable of bettering themselves independently.

I'm curious if this is a common sentiment, or it's just in my own head. If it is a common sentiment, is there a term or phrase that can better describe the mission of "empowerment", without a condescending connotation?

Comment: An interesting first part to the question that may give rise to opinion: mine is that usually "empowerment" means giving someone something (i) that is short of an enforceable right and (ii) that they already have if they are willing to use it (as long as it does not interfere with the business model. It is so broad as to be meaningless - I suppose then that it is condescending - or at least overly extended for commercial purposes. I think "help" (verb or noun - perhaps plus an adjective/adverb) would work well.

Comment: Mission, empowerment, improve the experience etc. etc. All bullshit. And nobody is impressed because the words don't mean anything any more. And what is a collectable niche? Is it comfortable? Why not say what you are and what you do in plain English. That way, people might be able to understand what you are selling and whether they need it.

Comment: It might be more empowering to say you empower or boost a certain quality than to paint a more static picture of empowerment. Is that a state of being the goal?

Comment: The fact that so many organizations and movements use that term to describe their own missions suggests that they don't see it as condescending.

Comment: @David the service is largely free - the message we are trying to convey is we exist to benefit collectors. This needs to be said as there is some preexisting distrust within the community that an organization of our nature would exist for this reason. For example, think of a social network that markets itself as built for the benefit the community, rather than to exploit the community as is commonly perceived by organizations like Facebook. We will then proceed to describe what we do in plain English, but we first want to answer the "why" of what we are doing, before getting into the "what".

Answer (score 2):

"Knowledge is power," right?

I would take "empowerment" in that vein.

Maybe you could try to figure out what other reasons lead you to dislike the phrase.

The only way I could see this phrase being condescending would be if the visitor takes offense because they already saw themselves as empowered, before visiting.  Or because the organization doesn't respect the visitors because it chose a cliché mission statement summary.  But both of these seem unlikely, unless your target audience is extremely touchy.

However, maybe a phrase involving "serving the collector community" would come across more humble and would make you more comfortable.

Comment: 'The only way I could see this phrase being condescending would be if the visitor takes offense because they already saw themselves as empowered, before visiting.' While this answer presents this as relatively unimportant, some people may see it as crucial. *Empowerment* implies that its recipient needs empowering. Moreover, it implies that whoever provides the empowering is in some way superior to its recipient (unless the empowering is mutual).

Comment: @jsw29 - I guess, but maybe not always.  "Hey, brother, come with me to the Million Man March.  It'll be empowering."